# Getting error : ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

Tags: python, sockets, ubuntu

I am trying to run this on Ubuntu

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("10.0.2.15", 5555)) #10.0.2.15 is the Kali IP
s.send("Connected!\n")  
data_received = s.recv(1024)
print(data_received)
s.close()
```

While running

```
‐v ‐l ‐p 5555 this on kali
```

But i keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "client.py", line 4, in <module>
    s.connect(("10.0.2.15", 4444)) 
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Comment: I doubt you can be _running

`‐v ‐l ‐p 5555 this on kali`_.

Comment: What's more, the error doesn't belong to the Python code shown.